# MYSQL, PHP Insert into Multiple Tables in Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to insert information into multiple tables within a database, i have managed to get it to work using this:

```
  $query = "INSERT INTO users (grp, email, college_id, tutor, year, password, register_date) VALUES ('$g', '$e', '$ci', '$tu', '$y', PASSWORD('$p'), NOW() )";
  $query2 = "INSERT INTO unit_26 (college_id) VALUES ('$ci')";
  $result = mysql_query ($query); // Run the Query Now woooo. 
  $result2 = mysql_query ($query2); // Run the Query Now woooo. 
  if ($result) { // If it Ran OK.
```

Although it works and the information is added to both tables, I was just wondering if anyone has a better way of doing this, or of this way is wrong?

Comment: what's wrong with it at the moment?

Comment: nothing, it does work fine, i've just posted it here to see if this is the correct way of doing it, or if there is an easier way or doing it

Comment: why? if you have a lunch consists of two dishes, is there a way to make it "easier" other than just eat them in order? you have 2 queries, you run it regular way. What makes you so uneasy?

Comment: Maybe he senses [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)?

Comment: @aaz another stupid site out of dumb comic. What if I have to create SQL statement that include outside data?

Comment: @Col. - I thought that that was the canonical link we used for questions featuring SQL injection.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Aren't you the one always [railing about solutions that are vulnerable to SQL injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019875/how-to-get-an-integer-output-from-an-sql-query/5019910#5019910)

Comment: @Robert sometimes. But I never post links to the lame sites

Comment: @aaz Canonical? How come it become canonical? This site contains empty rant only and no real help. It's only purpose is to just raise some money from popular character. There are no good explanations nor real life examples nor common pitfalls. That smarta55 just copy-pasted some texts just like he copypasted the character. It's disgusting and shameful site, not canonical.

Comment: @Col I agree its quality could be improved, but where is that site making money?

Comment: @Pekka it's just matter of time. you know, google ads to cover hosting fees or whatever of the kind. It's not the main point though. It's the only sense I can see in this site.

Comment: @Col, sorry, but it's a good site. It illustrates the problem and shows [solutions for PHP](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html). Don't like it? [Fix it](http://github.com/petdance/bobby-tables). Or link to whatever _you_ like.

Comment: @aaz As I have said already, it's plastic, dummy, non-real life examples. There are lots of nuances to understand. But there are not a single explanation. It's even doesn't explain why the code from the comic will never work in mysql driver. That's THE main problem of both this site and stackoverflow - lack of understanding. Friggin LOTS of people who says "do this! do that!" but hardly a few of them even tried *that*! No, really, it's not a exaggeration, it's a fact. Everyone recommend a thing or a solution they never tried themselves.

Comment: and these children fears. "prepared statements are safer than escaping" (LOL!), "prepared statements will make you safe" (LOL!). Don't you see it's more a chant or a prayer rather than an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these two inserts are executed independently, another program running concurrently might see the database in a state where the first insert is done but the second isn't.

Whether this is a problem or not depends on the application logic. In your case it's hard to tell without additional information. Probably not. A financial transactions involving two accounts is an example where this *is* a problem: you don't want the sum of all account balances to be wrong at any time.

If you think you need this, you can make the operation atomic at the cost of performance: another program will either see the database before the first insert, or after the second insert. It works like this:

```
$result = FALSE;
if (mysql_query('BEGIN')) {
    if (mysql_query($query1) &&
        mysql_query($query2))
        $result = mysql_query('COMMIT'); // both queries looked OK, save
    else
        mysql_query('ROLLBACK'); // problems with queries, no changes
}
```

The storage engine has to support transactions, i.e., it has to be [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html). Otherwise this will silently not work.

Answer (score 0):

SQL inserts are for a single table only. You can't insert data into two or more tables at the same time with a single INSERT query. You can force the separate insertions to be atomic by using a transaction, but you still have to do an INSERT for each table.

Might be nice if you could so something like

```
INSERT INTO t1.id, t2.val, t3.other VALUES ($t1id, $t2val, $t3other);
```

but alas...