# How to INSERT value to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I'm trying to add value to database when each voter will vote with his ID. 
My db get the value but it goes one row down and i want that the db to get the value 1 to ID row not one row down.

Any solution about this please!!!

This is my code

```
$before1    = $row['vote_one_before'];
$after1     = $row['vote_one_after'];
$before2    = $row['vote_two_before'];
$after2     = $row['vote_two_before'];
$before3    = $row['vote_three_before'];
$after3     = $row['vote_three_after'];

$vote = 1;

if(($before1 == 0) and ($after1 == 0) and ($before2 == 0) and ($after2 == 0) and ($before3 == 0) and ($after3 == 0)){
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO DB (vote_one_before) VALUES(':vote_one_before')");
    $stmt->execute(array(':vote_one_before'=> $vote));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL, PHP Insert into Multiple Tables in Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021557/mysql-php-insert-into-multiple-tables-in-database)

Answer (score 0):

### Issue 1: If/Else

`AND` is not an operator that can be used in an `IF/ELSE` function - you need `&&`. Change your `IF` line to:

```
if(($before1 == 0)&&($after1 == 0)&&($before2 == 0)&&($after2 == 0)&&($before3 == 0)&&($after3 == 0)){
```

---

### Issue 2: Query

Your query is also incorrect. For `INSERT`, the format is:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`column_name`) VALUES (`new_value`);
```

Unless "DB" is your table name, you'll need to amend your query to something like this:

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `table_name` (vote_one_before) VALUES (:vote_one_before)");
```

Also note that when using placeholders you don't need single or double quotes - so `':vote_one_before'` becomes `:vote_one_before`.

Comment: You are wrong in issue 1: there is an `and` operator in PHP and due to the parentheses it would work well here. But of course, `and` is to be used when you want to have for example your assignment operator higher precedence than the logical operation -- `$a = $b or something()` would execute something only if $b is false -- and in `if` clauses one would normally use `&&`. But the information you give here is simply incorrect. Consult http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php